# Automatically assign parent category to sub-category entries?

Tags: expressionengine

I have a parent category called, 'Reviews', which has sub-categories, 'Albums', 'Tracks' and 'Gigs'.

The entries in the sub-categories had already been assigned those sub-categories before the parent category was created.

Is there any way I can automatically add the 'Reviews' (parent) category to all of its sub-category entries?

Comment: You might want to move this question to the EE StackExchange site: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Anna_MediaGirl Thanks – I'll do that.